# How can I write a client/server program running on an Ethernet interface?

Tags: python, ethernet

I am trying to write a Python binary decoder/encoder and I have been struggling to figure out how to write it when it is running on an ethernet interface like eth0. This is the code I have for the client side currently:

```
import socket
port = 8888
host = 'localhost'
my_tuple = (host, port)
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(my_tuple)
server_socket.listen() 
client, address = server_socket.accept()
print("Connection from ", address)
message = client.recv(1024)
message = ' '.join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(i), 'b') for i in message.decode())
client.close()
```

Is there any way I can implement this running on an ethernet interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ethernet interface (eth0 or whatever), if connected, will likely have an IP address associated with it. Try binding to `0.0.0.0` or $IP address.

So, replace `host='localhost'` with `host='0.0.0.0'` for it to bind to all addresses, or, alternatively, have it bind to a specific IP address.

Localhost is a *loopback* address, so only clients on the *same* machine can talk to programs listening on localhost. This is commonly used for internal daemons, testing.

0.0.0.0 tells the kernel to listen in on **all** IP addresses associated with a given machine.

Individually specifying an IP address instructs the kernel to listen in on a *specific* address. This call will fail if you listen to an address the machine does not have.

Comment: Thanks this was it. I just had to replace the host with that or the IPv4 address. Got it. Cannot upvote cause I do not have 15 reputation